# Open a window from a dart command line app

Tags: dart

I have a dart command line app. From that I would like to sometimes open a small window. I don't really care if it is a flutter window or a native ui window, as long as it works on all desktop platforms.

I have tried including the flutter sdk, but then the dart vm goes on to assume that the whole thing is a flutter app, which it is not really. There don't seem to be any packages to do this, nor any answers on the internet.

Comment: A Dart command line app is not a Flutter app. Create a genuine Flutter app for Windows, MacOS and Linux.

Comment: @RoslanAmir I know, but I am not creating a flutter app. I'm creating a command line app that occasionally opens a small window.

Comment: You have to use Dart to work directly with each OS's native UI via whatever interface is available for each. And please remove the tags "flutter" and "flutter-desktop" from this question. :)

Comment: There does not seem to be a dart package for interacting with the native UI interface. I don't feel like implementing it separately for each platform.

Comment: The only way I know is to use Flutter for desktop. Since you are averse to using Flutter, the only way is to use Dart FFI. It allows you to call C API on each native platform.

Comment: Well, it would be great to use flutter, but as far as I know, it is not possible to just open a flutter window in the middle of a dart terminal process. I'm not going to go the Dart FFI or C API route.

Comment: If you don't want to use FFI, your options become pretty limited. You could launch a web server and open a web UI, or perhaps run a Python script to show a UI.